# Sending a file to Janome 10001 - failure to initialize communication port msg

Tags: windows-7

I have a Janome 10001, Customizer 10,000Plus, Embird 2010, on a Windows7 32bit computer with Microsoft Word 2007.  When attempting to send a design to the sewing machine I receive a Failed to Initialize Communication Port message.  I do not know why.  Can anyone with the same problem help?

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer? Restarting your sewing machine?

Comment: Is it plugged into the computer?

Comment: I not experienced with stewing machine software, but generally it mean hardware not connected or driver not installed properly. If default magic (switch off computer and machine, disconnect power cords, wait 20 s, connect all again) not help,  may be wrongly detected device stuck in device manager. Try delete device without driver in device manager and reconnect machine...

Answer (score -1):

RE: Failed to initialize communication port
When was the last time you connected to your machine. The 10000 won't be recognized by newer Windows Programs. I think XP was the last version that communicate with the sewing machine via the cable. Your PC card should work, but it may need to be formatted. You can do that in the newer version of Windows, by inserting it into the computer, finding the drive assigned to it - probably "E, F, G, etc." Right click on it, in the dropdown menu click "Format", then make sure that "FAT" is in the window about 3 from the top, do a full format (not the quick). You will be told that everything will be erased, Click OK and let it format. However, if you have things on the card you need to keep, copy them to your desktop in a folder to retrieve later. Then you need to format the card in your sewing machine, it might happen automatically, by just putting it into the sewing machine - can't remember as I've not had a 10000 for 10 years and don't remember the sequence. Your manual should tell you something or do a search on this website about formatting a card.

Hope this helps you some. Your card could also be corrupt at they don't last forever. I hope you have another as they aren't easy to get anymore.

Cheryl
Posted: Feb 29 2016 By: CherylAnn